# Работа с upload_max_filesize

Tags: php

Добрый день, дамы и господа! Помогите, пожалуйста, в решении такой проблемы. Необходимо загрузить на сервер файлы большого размера (до 30 М). В **php.ini** есть две директивы:
`upload_max_filesize=2М` и `post_max_size=8М`. Хочу динамически изменить. В начале страницы пишу:

```
<?php 
    if (ini_set("upload_max_filesize","30M")) {$a=1;} else {$a=0;}
    if (ini_set("post_max_size","40M")) {$b=1;} else {$b=0;}
    echo $a."<br>".$b;
?>
```

Переменные a и b равны нулю (неуспех функции `ini_set`). При отправке формы с файлами большого размера массивы `$_POST` и `$_FILES` пусты, меньшего размера - не пусты. Или на сервере host'a эти директивы будут другие?

Comment: По поводу этих директив и возможности настройки в скрипте, общайтесь с хостером.

Answer (score 3):

[Список директив](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), [что значит колонка Changeable](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) - как видно, эти директивы не устанавливаются в скриптах через ini_set().

Comment: Спасибо, большое, yozh! Создал файл .htaccess в корневом каталоге сайта с содержимым:
php_value post_max_size  40M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
Заработало!!!

Comment: Странно.. yozh ни слова не написал о .htaccess (в отличие от меня), но заслужил благодарность..

Answer (score 3):

Эти директивы могут быть установлены только из `php.ini`, `.htaccess` или `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, люди добрые! Вы спасли меня. `.htaccess` - то, что надо. Кто не знает, как создать `.htaccess`, делаем следующее:

1. В корне своего сайта создаём текстовый документ.
2. Прописываем к примеру `php_value post_max_size 40M php_value upload_max_filesize 30M`
3. Далее "Сохранить как", в поле имя прописываем `.htaccess`, в поле файл ставим выбор на "Все файлы(*)" или англ. версия "All Files(*)", выбираем директорию, куда сохранить, и жмём кнопку "Сохранить".

Comment: Не забывай что .htaccess это не единственное место.. Изменения в .htaccess ограничиваются одним проектом. Обрати внимание на использование php.ini и httpd.conf. Ты сможешь сконфигурировать сервер по своему вкусу )